# predictBinomial method slow from Java code

Tags: h2o

I am new to H2o. I am calling the predictBinomial method from a Java application and I am getting the correct results back, but it takes a long time to respond. Here is my scenario:

I am exposing a web service method where I receive the name of the class (modelName) and using ClassLoader to load it (the idea is to allow business users to upload their compiled models to the server and be able to call the service without any development required):

```
ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(
                new URL[]{new URL(String.format("%s%s/", H2O_MODELS_URI, modelName))}, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

then I instantiate the raw model:

```
hex.genmodel.GenModel rawModel = (hex.genmodel.GenModel) classLoader.loadClass(modelName).newInstance();
```

Instantiate the wrapper:

```
EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(rawModel);
```

Prepare the RowData (modelParameters received as service parameters):

```
RowData row = _h20ParametersMapper.map(modelParameters);
```

Until here, everything goes smoothly, but when I call

```
BinomialModelPrediction binomialPrediction = model.predictBinomial(row);
```

It takes more than 10 seconds to return a response, which doesn't work for us. Do you see any way I could gain some performance? I am referencing the h2o-genmodel:3.18.0.3 library.

Thanks!

Comment: Many people use predictBinomial in real-time use cases with microsecond or millisecond latencies.  So it sounds like you are either doing something wrong, or you somehow created a model that is just way too big.  Another thing to try is using the MOJO instead of the POJO.  That can run much faster for really deep tree models.

Comment: How long does it take, on that row of data, in the environment where the model was trained (i.e. R, Python or Flow)? IIUC (@TomKraljevic can correct me) it will predict using exactly the same Java code. So if it is slow in the H2O cluster, too, then the model is just big and slow. And if not you either have a bug in your Java code, or are not giving it enough memory?

Comment: @DarrenCook the MOJO is very similar to in-H2O scoring.  The POJO is not similar at all.

Comment: Hi, if I create a main class and run it directly in the server, the response times are good:
real 0m1.492s
user 0m0.985s
sys 0m0.406s
In the Java application I am getting the correct results back, but with bad performance. I will research the memory issue you mention. Thanks

Comment: Also, the Java JIT compiler needs to warm up when seeing new methods.  So don't measure it on the very first prediction.  The MOJO is not as sensitive to this warmup as the POJO (since the MOJO is not generated code).

Comment: Hi, after multiple tests, the solution was to include the POJO inside the Java application and not load it remotely with the class loader. I am now getting processing times of less than a second. Regards.